# Vertica sporadically having connection errors

Tags: database, odbc, vertica

I'm trying to run a query which, when successful, executes in 500-600 ms.  However, sometimes the query fails and gives a message saying it couldn't connect to the server.  The exact message is

`Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Vertica][VerticaDSII] (10) An error occurred during query preparation: no connection to the server\n (10) (SQLExecDirectW)')`

What is the root cause of this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Where are you connecting *from*?

Comment: I'm connecting from a python process running on an AWS EC2 instance.  The process connects to Vertica using the pyvertica module.

Comment: Trying pinging the vm for awhile. My bet is you have transient packet loss.